# Options for submitting prior art on a patent application after the 6 month window passed?

Tags: prior-art, pre-grant, disclosure, third-party-submission, public-disclosure

There's a patent application close to issuance for an "invention" we have significant pieces of prior art for, but the time allowed for third party submissions under 35 U.S.C. 122(e) has passed.

[MPEP 2202 and 2204](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2204.html) seem to say anyone can submit prior art at anytime, but I guess this only for already issued patents.

Another option seems to be sending the prior art to the applicant, as they are under a duty to disclose 37 CFR 1.56.

Are there any other alternatives/options? Thanks so much.

Comment: What about just reaching out to the patent examiner reviewing the pending application, sending them the prior art and letting them know? Has anyone ever heard of such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only preissuance submittance of prior art I've heard outside of the 6-month third party prior art window, is an attorney for a third party just calling up the examiner:
http://patentlyo.com/patent/2011/04/third-party-attempts-to-protest-or-otherwise-oppose-the-grant-of-a-published-application.html